# App component keeps calling the axios.get many times over in a react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App function (reactjs here), I am making a call to an api, and then in the .then I am making many more api calls with await to get more details. This is an illustration using a public api for pokemon. The main call loads a summary, then each record is called again to fill in the details.

The problem I am having is that App() is called many, many times, and so the api calls are repeated over and over eventually leading to the browser to crash. I think the reason why is that I am updating the progress state as I move through the loop which causes the function to rerun. But I'm not sure how to stop it calling the initial axios.get again.

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import "./styles.css"

function App() {
  let [allDataJson, setAllData] = useState(null);
  let [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=200").then(async (response) => {
          const newData = [];
          // API returns result in blocks, with next pointing to next block
          do{
            for(var item of response.data.results)
              newData.push(item);
            response = await axios.get(response.data.next);
          } while(response.data.next);
          for(const item of newData) {
            item.detail = await getDetails(item.url);
            setProgress(progress+1);
          }
          setAllData(JSON.stringify(newData));
        });
  return (
    <div>
      { allDataJson ? (
        <div>Completed Load</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading, please wait....{progress}</div>
      )
    }
    </div>
  );
}
const cache = {};

export async function getDetails(url) {
  // url is in form "host/.../id/" where id is unique number.
  const split = url.split('/');
  const code = 'code' + split[split.length - 2];
  if(cache.hasOwnProperty(code))
    return cache[code];
  else {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;
    cache[code] = data;
    return data;
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried this ugly hack. This did prevent it from calling the api too many times but the html did not render.

```
function App() {
  let [allDataJson, setAllData] = useState(null);
  let [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  if(!started) {
      started = true;
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=200").then(async (response) => {
... same as above ...
        });
      }
  return (
    <div>
      { allDataJson ? (
        <div>Completed Load</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this goal. (It takes a while to load all this, so really I'd like a simple progress bar, or maybe even a background "thread" as in a setTimeout to do the same thing.)

Obviously, fairly new to react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the axios call in a `useEffect` function.

Import `useEffect` alongside `useState` at the top:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
```

And you App function should look more like this:

```js
function App() {
  let [allDataJson, setAllData] = useState(null);
  let [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get...
  }, []) // notice the empty array will cause the function to only be called once when the app loads since it is not dependent on any other variables.
  return (
   ...
  );
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.